# Make content editable div get focus on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a content editable div that I'm using to retrieve some data.

```
<div contenteditable="true" ref="test">/*SomeText*/</div>
```

After running the focus through the `ref` with `this.$refs.test.focus()`. It didn't work and I get an error on the console (Cannot read properties of `undefined` reading `focus`)
How can I trigger a focus effect on content editable div?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which error do you get?

Comment: I only tried this.$refs.test.focus() but seems like its not working, I guess I'll have to create a custom directive for it ...

Answer (score 3):

The attribute for content editable should not be `content-editable="true"`, but instead `contenteditable="true"`.

```js
const App = {
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    focusDiv() {
      this.$refs.test.focus()
    }
  }
}

const app = new Vue(App)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div contenteditable="true" ref="test">My Div</div>
  <button @click="focusDiv">Focus on div</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what is $el because when I put it like that I just get the same error

Comment: $el was wrong it seems. That might've been for an outdated vue version. I've updated my answer

Comment: is it the same thing for spans or anything else that is content editable?

Comment: It should be the same